# Is there any way on Facebook to get a message to someone if they have their message option turned off?

Tags: facebook

Say I choose to make I so no one can look me up on Facebook.

I can still be found in any way, for example if my name is mentioned in a picture just click on he name link then you're on my page.

So what if someone I know very well has their message option turned off and I have very important news to give them (I've tried email, phone, every thing). Is there a way with all the other tricks on face book there has to be a way